# Sphinx autodoc: inherit docstrings without inheriting class

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have two classes which share an API through duck typing, but do not share any inheritance:

```
class A:
    def method():
        """Does something."""
        pass

class B:
    def method():
        pass
```

I have written docstrings for `A`, but not `B`. Since the two classes share the same API semantics, their docstrings are mostly the same. I do not wish to repeat the same docstrings in two different places.

If `B` inherited from `A`, then autodoc has tools to inherit parent class docstrings, but I don't want `B` to inherit from `A`.

I could make both classes inherit from an `abc.ABC` abstract class and put the docstrings there, but that would be a lot of added code for no purpose other than documentation.

Is there any way to tell autodoc to copy the docstrings from another class?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can tell autodoc to do that, but you can copy it in the code:

```
class A:
    def method():
        """Does something."""
        pass

class B:
    def method():
        pass
    method.__doc__ = A.method.__doc__
```